# How can I link my JavaScript file properly with enqueue in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have made sure that `wp_head()` is in head and `wp_footer()` before the end of the body.

My stylesheets are loading fine, but I cannot get simple `scripts.js` file to load. I've tried different parameters, etc.

Edit:
including:
I've tried adding it to the header, which worked for style.css, turning off all plugins, different boolean values where allowed, null where allowed. different names, calling get_stylesheet_directory instead of get_template_directory.

Here is my `functions.php`:

```
<?php

function load_stylesheets() 
{

    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri(). '/style.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('style');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');


function loadJs()
{

    wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/scripts.js', '', 1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadJs');

?>
```

Edit 2:

The strangest thing. With the code listed above, I sort of gave up and went on to work on another area. Suddenly, about fifteen minutes later, the js file was linked.

All I had done differently where js is concerned is done a workaround with bootstrap files and linked them using the CDN links below wp_footer(), which worked fine, allowing me to at least continue work at that point.

I don't think that is related, but it's all that had changed. After the js file was linked, I linked bootstrap the same way.  Similarly, it did not link right away. I did not change the code, and a couple minutes later- linked. So odd.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Benton. When asking a question it's useful to state what you've already tried, rather than "I've tried different parameters, etc...", please try improving your question to help others answer it for you.

Comment: I've tried adding it to the header, which worked for style.css, turning off all plugins, different boolean values where allowed, null where allowed. different names, calling get_stylesheet_directory instead of get_template_directory.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try with this code:

```
function load_stylesheets() 
{

    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri(). '/style.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('style');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');


function loadJs()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadJs');

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had tried that as well. It was the strangest thing. With the code listed above, I sort of gave up and went on to work on another area. Suddenly, about fifteen minutes later, the js file was linked (longer message put under edit above).